# "Geometry type does not exist" on a Postgis installation on Fedora 18

Tags: postgis, fedora

Just installed PostgreSql and PostGIS over a brand new installation of Fedora 18. I did it this way:

```
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server postgrsql-contrib postgresql-devel pgadmin3
```

Once installed PostgreSql, I created the postgres user as usual.

Then, I installed PostGIS:

```
sudo yum install proj-devel gdal postgis
```

As a last step, I've created a new user (mydbuser) and a new db owned by that user:

```
psql -U postgres -W
CREATE DATABASE mydb OWNER mydbuser;
\q
createlang plpgsql mydb
```

Now, I've tried to execute the following line to use PostGIS on mydb:

```
psql -d mydb -U mydbuser -W -f /usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql
```

but I get a long list of errors of the same type, this is the first line:

```
psql:/usr/share/pgsql/contrib/postgis-64.sql:7751: ERRORE:  il tipo "geometry" non esiste
```

In English, the message is 'ERROR: "geometry" type does not exist'.
I've also tried to execute the code as the postgres user, but nothing changed. Any ideas?

Diego

Comment: Are those the exact lines you've entered? Can you double check?

Comment: which version of postgis?

Comment: I've used the default packages of Fedora 18. Postgis version is 1.5.

Comment: @BradHards Now I'm going to check, removing all the packages and doing it all again, meanwhile I've edited the post and added the createlang statement, that I executed as required by the postgis manual but I forgot to write.

Comment: @BradHards I removed the postgis package and installed it again, then I tried tcreate a new post database owned by the postgres user, but the error I get is still the same.

Comment: postgrsql-contrib ? really?

Comment: @BradHards: it's postgresql-contrib, but that wasn't the problem. I'm writing the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the old/incompatible version of PostGIS is to blame, install PostGIS 2.0 from PGDG. Use the PGDG YUM RPM method, described here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation with package `postgis2`. There is an older guideline [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Fedora16pgdg) to help out.

Comment: I posted a detailed list of instructions on my web site: http://www.diegognesi.it/?p=196.

Comment: Please write the complete answer here, not just links.

Comment: @steko: sorry for linking a page in my own blog, I did it because the real and precise solution to the problem is the one already linked by Mike (from the postgresql wiki). My page is only a sort of step-by-step guide about setting up PostgreSQL and PostGIS 2 on Fedora 18, and goes out of the scope of my original question. I linked it only for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in Fedora 18 itself. Default repos will install postgis 1.5 and potgresql 9.2.4, but this two versions are not compatible.
This is the compatibility table:

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostgreSQLPostGIS

And this post seems to point out the problem:

http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/F18-Postgresql-9-2-x-PostGIS-1-5-x-issues-td5002414.html

...And an update ha been planned for Fedora 18 in order to resolve this issue:

https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/player-3.0.2-24.fc18,gdal-1.9.1-15.fc18.1,grass-6.4.2-5.fc18,geos-3.3.7-1.fc18,postgis-2.0.2-2.fc18

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to [another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850500/postgis-installation-type-geometry-does-not-exist/6864701#6864701). Add `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` to the `psql` command to see the first error.

Comment: The error I've posted is already first one. The others are similar.

Comment: How did you determine it was the first error? It shouldn't be possible. The first error is the only useful error, all others are just noise.

Comment: I red the output text from the beginning to the end and taken the first error. If I use the ON_ERROR_STOP=1 option, the error is "C" language does not exist, as documented in the second link posted in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual you should either create the db from template:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_spatial_db TEMPLATE=template_postgis
```

Or add an extension in your database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: Both the lines return an error. The first one returns:
ERRORE:  il modello di database "template_postgis" non esiste (en: ERROR: database model "template_postgis" does not exist);

Comment: ...the second one returns:
ERRORE:  apertura del file di controllo dell'estensione "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/postgis.control" fallita: File o directory non esistente

(en: the specified file or directory for the extension does not exist).

Comment: @diegogb I don't have a clue then, sorry. But I can tell you that `SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';` will change the error messages to english so at least that might be a bit help.